# Why is this 'margin' here?

Tags: html, css

i'm working on my website, and right now i'm working on a new navigation, the old one used inline tables and table-cells and stuff and I wanted to make a dropdown for it, so I had to move to using nav, ul, and li. [This is an image of what it looks like.](http://vxservers.net/uhh.png)
I want the tabs (home, forum, servers, and information) to be right on top of the black box [like this.](http://vxservers.net/yes.png)

I got it to look like what I want it to look like, but it only works on my resolution (it's a margin-top: -1%; on the content box). How would I get it to be how I want it to look? The link to the page i'm working on is vxservers.net/new. Also, would there be a way to get the tabs to be the widest they can, but all fit on that one line, minding other tabs? My old website vxservers.net had a tab container with a display: inline-table; and tabs with a display: table-cell, and it worked.

Here's all my nav code:

```
nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

nav ul {
    width: 94%;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-left: 6%;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li {
    background-image: url('http://www.photos-public-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/white-construction-paper-texture.jpg');
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-family: 'Exo 2';
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 0.2%;
    padding-bottom: 0.2%;
    padding-left: 0.2%;
    padding-right: 0.2%;
    color: black;
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: white;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 0;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 5px 40px;
    color: black;
}

nav ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't there a better place to come and ask css questions?

Comment: load the page in a decent browser and use the developer tools to inspect the elements. They all have a metrics debugger that will identify the source of your problem in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
nav > ul {margin-bottom: 0;}
```

The default margin on the `ul` is creating the space below it.